# Soot analysis for member fields access

Tags: soot

i would like to know if soot is able to analysis member field access? For example, if A accessed member fields of B, is soot able to detect this? And determine the name of the class for those members which were accessed in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's easy. Simple navigate through the JimpleBody and look for appropriate expressions, best using an ExprSwitch. And read the tutorials online!